# Best way to structure Python code that searches a string for different substrings

Tags: python, if-statement

I am making a football commentary scraper using BeautifulSoup as my first project since trying to learn python.

Basically for each Goal statement, it could either be a goal, an own goal, or a penalty, I need these recorded separately in my database.

The problem that occurs is that sometimes the Goal statement contains 'penalty area' or 'penalty box' so I need to record these occasions as Goals rather than Penalties.

I mocked something up with loads of nested statements but it was dirty as hell.

so originally I had something along the lines of

```
if goal in statement:
   if 'own goal' in statement:
      {record own goal in db}
   elif 'penalty' in statement:
      if not 'penalty area' in statement:
          if not 'penalty box' in statement:
              {record penalty in db}
   else:
      {record goal in db}
```

I have just mocked that together as I don't have the code with me.  Is this the only way to achieve this?

Comment: should your first line read: `if 'goal' in statement:` ?  Or is `goal` a variable name?

Comment: yeah it should be 'goal'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is better:

```
   if 'goal' in statement:
       if 'own goal' in statement:
           {record own goal in db}
       elif not('penalty area' in statement or 'penalty box' in statement):
           {record goal in db}
       elif 'penalty' in statement:
           {record penalty in db}
       else:
           {record goal in db}
```

Comment: ah I guess I didn't explain it well, thought this might happen.  It needs to be recorded as a goal if it contains 'penalty area' or 'penalty box' but as a penalty if 'penalty' appears alone in the statement.

Answer (score 0):

To clean it up, you can maybe combine some logical statements, but apart from that I don't see much improvement.

```
if 'goal' in statement:
    if 'own goal' in statement:
        {record own goal}
    elif 'penalty' in statement and not('penalty area' in statement) and not('penalty box' in statement):
        {record penalty}
    else:
        {record goal}
```

Comment: This is the same as the answer by gperetin, I just noticed, except there he forgot the 'penalty' part and I think there's also a difference in the main loop, because there statements without goals will be recorded as goals actually. So I'm leaving this up!

Comment: Do you mean to call `not('pentalty area')`?  i think you should check the parentheses.